# I want to add a random Maps Activity Location, how can I do it?

Tags: google-maps, kotlin, random, location

I want to add a button to my map, every time this button is clicked, I want to turn the camera to a different location. How can I do it? I can't generate a random location
What I can do at the moment is the location of the user, adding a listening marker, a number of more operations depending on the location he chose
I can do it, I want the camera to go anywhere in the world with the menu key I assigned. How can I do it?

override fun onLocationChanged(p0: Location) {

```
            mMap.clear()
            val guncelKonum =LatLng(p0.latitude,p0.longitude)

                println("${p0.latitude}"+"${p0.longitude}")

                mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(guncelKonum).title("Guncel Konumunuz"))
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(guncelKonum,12f))

                val geocoder =Geocoder(this@MapsActivity, Locale.getDefault())
                try {
                    val adresListesi=  geocoder.getFromLocation(p0.latitude,p0.longitude,1)
                    if (adresListesi.size>0){
                        println(adresListesi.get(0).toString())
                    }

                }catch (e:Exception){
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }

        }

    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),1)

    }else {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1,1f,locationListener)
        val sonBilinenkonum = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
        if (sonBilinenkonum !=null){
            val sonbilinenLatLang =LatLng(sonBilinenkonum.latitude,sonBilinenkonum.longitude)
            mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sonbilinenLatLang).title("Son Bilinen Konumunuz"))
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sonbilinenLatLang,12f))
        }

    }


}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    if (requestCode==1){
        if (grantResults.size > 0){
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1,4f,locationListener)
            }
        }
    }
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
}
```

Comment: The code shown has an unbalanced number of curly braces - 13 opening and 15 closing..

Comment: @Professor Abronsius 
I could not share the entire code, I want to do it in a separate button to show the things I use.